# Where can I find software for the PDP-6?

Tags: pdp-6, software, dec

We are planning to [build a reconstruction](https://github.com/aap/pdp6) of the [PDP-6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-6). The project is making a lot of progress, but currently we have a critical lack of software. Does anybody know where we can find software to run on the reconstructed machine?

Answer (score 6):

Bitsavers has some PDFs of printouts of [tsExec1.4](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/dec/pdp6/tsExec1.4/). Not sure if this is complete.

There's a lot of PDP-10 software e.g. at [trailing-edge](http://pdp-10.trailing-edge.com/), I suppose at least some of that could be adapted to run on the PDP-6 (but you probably already thought of that).

Comment: We have a digital copy of that program, but thank you for the link!

Comment: could you share it with bitsavers, then?

Answer (score 5):

Old versions of the Monitor:
http://pdp-6.trailing-edge.com/

PDP-6 notes from ITS, includes some PDP-6 programs:
https://github.com/PDP-10/its/issues/278

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing!  As it stands, this is a borderline link-only answer.  While the link may answer the question, it would add value to you answer if you could elaborate on the contents of your links and ITS.

Answer (score 5):

Update.  There is now quite a bit of PDP-6 software, but almost all of it from MIT:

- Monitor from DEC.
- SYSTEM GEN, low level DECtape formatting.
- MACDMP, file system on DECtapes.
- DDT, debugger.
- TECO, editor.
- MIDAS, assembler.
- STINK, linker.
- LISP.
- Spacewar!
- LIFE.
- MacHack VI... we have a timesharing version, unsure if it runs standalone on a PDP-6.
- David Silver's flight simulator.

Get the latest updates here: https://github.com/PDP-10/its/issues?q=label%3Apdp6

EDIT: This was created to collect everything:
https://github.com/PDP-6/pdp6-programs

Answer (score 4):

The program was MAC HACK VI.  This link doesn't give access to the program, but it may give you some leads about where to find it.  It was a chess playing program, and a good one for its time frame.  https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Mac+Hack

Also, here's a link to pdp- TECO.  The best text editor around in 1965.  This link does have a Download button, which I have not tried.

https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/5917

You might also want SHRDLU, 
 a language understanding prgram written by Terry Winograd. You can get it here:

http://hci.stanford.edu/winograd/shrdlu/

Trouble is,  you'll also have to get MacLisp in order to run it.

Comment: I think I have a copy of MacHack, although it's not named as such.  I do have TECO and MacLisp up and running.

Comment: It has been confirmed to be MacHack VI.  I also have a second version which draws on a Type 340 display.  Both versions are running on a PDP-10 emulator.

Comment: The trouble with SHRDLU is not getting Maclisp, which we do have running.  It's that SHRDLU is written for an ancient version of Maclisp we don't have.

Answer (score 4):

A significant chunk of PDP-6 software has surfaced: JOSS.

https://www.rand.org/pubs/research_memoranda/RM5437.html

It's being typed in: https://github.com/PDP-6/JOSS-II