# Where can I find software for the Imlac computers?

Tags: software

There is an emulator for the Imlac PDS-1 and PDS-4 computers, but not a lot of software to run on it.  I know about this collection: http://www.ubanproductions.com/imlac_sw.html

Is there anything else out there?

Comment: This question in similar vein to https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-can-i-find-software-for-the-pdp-6

Comment: The emulator is here: https://github.com/jdersch/sImlac

Comment: Awesome!  Given the schematics for a PDS-1 are available I kind of want to build one now!

Comment: (It's too bad you can't tag _answers_ - I'd like to tag [this one](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13063/332) (which you commented on and which probably inspired you to ask this question...))

Comment: @davidbak, I was inspired because I started this: https://github.com/larsbrinkhoff/imlac-software